# How do we explode through nested struct in SPARK

Tags: json, apache-spark, hadoop2, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to find a way to explode below schema and retrieve below from each of the counters.

```
jobid & groups->element->counts->element->displayname, value
```

`

```
 |-- event: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.jobhistory.JobFinished: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- failedMaps: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- failedReduces: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- finishTime: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- finishedMaps: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- finishedReduces: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- jobid: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- mapCounters: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- groups: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- counts: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- displayName: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- value: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- displayName: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- reduceCounters: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- groups: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- counts: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- displayName: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- value: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- displayName: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- totalCounters: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- groups: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- counts: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- displayName: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- value: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- displayName: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- type: string (nullable = true)


scala> val df = sqlContext.read.json("hdfs:///xyz/jfinished.json")
var explodeDF3 = df.withColumn("org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.jobhistory.JobFinished",df("event.org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.jobhistory.JobFinished"))
```

> org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: No such struct field org in
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.jobhistory.JobFinished;

`**org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.jobhistory.JobFinished is a sruct**`

but throws above error. Is there a way around ?